# Kinetic.js not tweening image at all, not sure what Im doing incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, kineticjs, tween

Im just trying to have the image tween slowly to the left. As far as I can tell, the code is correct. The image loads, but there is no motion.

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    var space = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: imageObj,
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(space);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3768/11633218256_30a04f01c3_o.png';
  var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: space, 
    duration: 20,
    x: -1920,
    y: 0,
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    tween.play();
  }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few scoping problems with the code:

- Make sure your space and tween variables are in scope (currently hidden in .onload)
- Since the image will take time to load, you should start the tween in imageObj.onload

Here's code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/JT2cD/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 500,
        height: 500
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var space;
    var tween;

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
      space = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        image: imageObj,
        width: 1920/4,
        height: 1080/4
      });

      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(space);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);

      tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
        node: space, 
        duration: 20,
        x: -1920/4,
        y: 0,
      });

      setTimeout(function(){ tween.play(); }, 2000);

    };
    imageObj.src = 'http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3768/11633218256_30a04f01c3_o.png';

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome... thank you, its ALWAYS scope >.>... And now all I have to do is to figure out how to make the translation smooth in chrome. You wouldnt happen to know how to do that would you?